# Doubts about stability control theory

Tags: control, control-system, stability, control-theory

I have some questions about theory of stability:

1. Can a system be stable and have poles in the right semiplane of s plane?
2. If a system has poles in the right semiplane, what should happen in GH plane to be stable?
3. Stability criteria can be applied to systems with H(s)<>1 (<> = distinct)? or its necessary do some transformation in this case?

If someone can help me with this I'll be grateful!

Comment: 1- NO, right half plane means either a constant or a sinusoid multiplied by an exponent raised to a positive power which means a time function that diverges.  2- Figure out a controller with the proper poles and zeros that will lead to stability for some values of gain [you probably can figure this out from the root locus],  3-cant understand this question

Comment: As my professor once described right half poles: "The machine will be unstable and will try to suck all of the energy in the known universe in order to _try_ to become stable."

Comment: Also, see my question about poles and zeros [here](http://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/10848/in-control-systems-engineering-why-do-imaginary-poles-and-zeros-on-the-lhp-indi)

Comment: An example, this is an unstable system [https://i.stack.imgur.com/Omd12.png] After introducing a proper controller, this is the new system root locus and step response after setting the proper gain [https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocfZv.png]

Comment: @Elbehery in the third question i mean if the way to apply the stability criteria change if H(s) is not unitary (distinct to 1). assuming that the characteristic equation is 1+G(s)H(s)=0

Comment: It can have open-loop poles in the right half plane and be stable, e.g. \$\small GH= \large \frac{s+2}{s-1}\$

Answer (score 0):

1. No. The poles in the right semiplane are dual with unbounded exponential functions in the time domain: $$ {{1}\over{s - \alpha}} \leftrightarrow \exp(\alpha t) $$
2. Adding a control system \$G(s)\$ to the model \$H(s)\$ will alter the location of poles in a nonlinear way. Here you create a root locus plot to observe the combined relationship as a function of gain, usually denoted \$K\$. The only acceptable are K are those where the poles remaining the left semiplane.
3. What useful work can a system do if H(s) = 0 for all s?

Comment: sorry, bad type, must be H(s)<>1